# How do I add a method to Ruby Array class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, sorting

Trying to add a method to the Ruby Array class which takes a code block with two arguments. For every next run of equal items in the array, it calls the code block once, sending the length of the run and the item repeated. And an item which is not repeated will be a run of length 1, with the single item repeated once, like so

```
irb(main):001:0> [4,4,5,6,7,7].every_run {|ct,v| print v, "[", ct, "]\n" }
4[2]
5[1]
6[1]
7[2]
=> nil
```

Comment: How about an approach based on [`Enumerable#chunk`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk)? I want to try, but lack time :-(

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've written. It's really hard to tell you how to modify your code if you don't show it to us.

Comment: @Aspersum if array  is like `[4,4,5,6,7,7,4]` then what out put you are expecting or what is length of run for `4`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Array
  def every_run
    chunk(&:itself).map { |n,arr| yield(arr.size,n) }
  end
end

[4,4,5,6,7,7].every_run {|ct,v| print v, "[", ct, "]\n" }
4[2]
5[1]
6[1]
7[2]
```

Prior to v2.2, you would have to use

```
chunk { |e| e }
```

in place of `chunk(&:itself)`